# Change the executables name in monodevelop

Tags: .net, executable, monodevelop, rename

i just want to know how to change the name of the executable that monodevelop produces. I cant seem to find that option anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right-click your project, and choose "Options" from the context menu.
- In the left pane of the "Options" dialog, open the "Build" subtree.
- From the "Build" subtree, choose "Output".
- Use "Assembly name" property in the right pane to name your executable.

Comment: Although ... they've changed it :/  Heh!

Comment: Ah!  they didn't change it!  :)  in step 1 you have to right-click on your "project" as you say, not the "overall" "solution" level. Thanks again!  :)